# TextBox to Display Mouse Clicks

Tags: c#, visual-studio

my problem is that i'm trying to have a textbox display the number of times that I have clicked on the screen. I'm having the issue of not being able to take the textbox's text and convert it to a int. Thanks!

```
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Random rand = new Random();
    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(rand.Next(0, 750), rand.Next(0, 750));
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        {
           int mouseclick = 0;
           textBox1.Text = Int32.Parse(mouseclick);  

        }

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes:

```
 {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
        Random rand = new Random();
        public Form1()

        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Location = new Point(rand.Next(0, 750), rand.Next(0, 750));
        }

        int mouseclick = 0;

        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                mouseclick++;
            }

            textBox1.Text = mouseclick.ToString();

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
      }
    }
```

I have moved **mouseclick** out of the event so that it can maintain its value and i am only incrementing **mouseclick** if the user clicks with the left mouse button.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! Can you explain why the Int32.Parse wasn't working?

Comment: Please mark as answer if this helped you. It wasn't Int32 that wasn't working. Its the way you declared mouseclick. It is supposed to be declared outside the Form1_MouseClick so that it can maintain its value.

Comment: You welcome! Besides mouseclick is already an integer so no need of Int32.Parse(mouseclick). You needed to convert it to a string instead using   mouseclick.ToString() which is exactly what i ve done.

Answer (score 0):

The textbox datatype is a string, but its assignment is a number being parsed as a number. Perhaps the following example would be helpful.

```
string mouseclick = "0";
int intMouseClick = Int32.Parse(mouseclick);
textBox1.Text = intMouseClick.ToString();
```

Comment: So the int32.parse would only work with just string vars and not the textbox datatype? And why is that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to convert an int into string bei using Int32.Parse(...).
But this function does the reverse conversion. It converts a string to an int.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are telling the program to set mouseclicks to 0 every single time it is clicked. You might instead want the code to read:

```
if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        {
           int mouseclick = mouseclick + 1;
           textBox1.Text = Int32.Parse(mouseclick);  

        }
```

or move the int out of the if statement and just do `mouseclick++;`

On top of that, if you are trying to set the text boxes text, you can do it much easier by just doing this:

```
textBox1.Text = mouseclick.ToString();
```